# I don't want to display ads to Facebook, Twitter Visitors

Tags: php, wordpress, http-referer

I am now using this code for facebook. **"https" is active and wordpress site.**

```
<?php

    $ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    if (strpos($ref, 'facebook.com') != false) {

?>

DON'T SHOW ADS

<?php } else { ?>

SHOW ADS

<?php }   ?>
```

This code works for facebook. I wanted to add twitter, but when I add twitter it doesn't work at all. I tried this.

```
if (strpos($ref, 'facebook.com', 'twitter.com', 't.co') != false) {
```

It didn't work that way. If else query or "false" is correct? How can I do it in the simplest way? If the visitor comes from Facebook, Twitter, I don't want to show ads. thanks

Comment: Print out `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. Click a link to your site from Twitter. See what it prints out. Adjust accordingly. (Also, `strpos` doesn't work the way you think it does. https://www.php.net/strpos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strpos()` does not check multiple "needles" to look for. You can store them in an array
and iterate over each one individually though:

```php
<?php
    
    $ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    $sitesWithAdsHidden = [
        'facebook.com',
        'twitter.com',
        't.co',
    ];
    
    $isHiddenSite = false;
    foreach ($sitesWithAdsHidden as $site) {
        if (strpos($ref, $site) !== false) {
            $isHiddenSite = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($isHiddenSite) {

?>

DON'T SHOW ADS

<?php } else { ?>

SHOW ADS

<?php }   ?>
```

Note that I also changed the `strpos` comparison to `!==` because a non-strict check could lead to evaluating to false if the position is actually `0` (the start of the string).

Comment: Thank you. I tried the code but it doesn't work right. It always shows ads. So "else" comes up always ?

Comment: have you confirmed that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` actually contains one of the domains in the list in your tests?

Comment: Silly me, the `$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` was too low of course so it did not contain a value. I edited my post to have it at the top, should work now.

Comment: point to note, the `HTTP_REFERER` does not need to be sent with the request. Ensure you check its not empty before accessing it else it will throw exceptions.

Comment: Jaquarh, twitter sends visitors with t.co. so I did it that way and it worked. thanks <?php

    $ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    if (preg_match('/facebook.com|t.co/', $ref) != false) {

?>

<?php } else { ?>

Comment: @HaberTimi you are encouraged to "accept" an answer that helped you out, see: [someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Ok,I did.. Both answers worked, thanks all. But I had to disable the cache plugin. I guess I can't use this with the cache plugin.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, directly from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer#:%7E:text=The%20referrer%20field%20is%20an,browser%20to%20the%20web%20server.):

> "*The referrer field is an **optional** part of the HTTP request sent by the web browser to the web server.*"

Therefore, you should always check that the Http Referer exists in the request. You can achieve this by using `!empty()` or `isset()`, however, for future maintainability, you can also use `array_diff` and `array_keys`.

You can then also achieve this without having to iterate over an array using `preg_match`.

```
if(!array_diff(['HTTP_REFERER'], array_keys($_SERVER)))
    if(preg_match('/facebook|twitter/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
        // todo: disable adverts
```

You could also use the `null cascading operator` to reduce this to one line. Do this if you have no further checks to make from the `$_SERVER` global variable.

```
if(preg_match('/facebook|twitter/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?? ''))
        // todo: disable adverts
```